# Limited input via Javascript to specific date format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a function which only allows numbers and slashes but my problem is it is not letting me input any numbers from my Numeric Keypad which i want it to?

Can anyone help here is my function:

```
function CheckDate(){



document.getElementById('txtbox').onkeydown = function(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && charCode != 191)
    return false;

    return true;

    }

}
```

or is there a better way i can do this.. i need it to go `DD/MM/YYYY` so allowing slashes and numbers + numerical pad.

Comment: Those are different keys. Even when numlock is on. The keypress event should however return the same values.

Comment: Anything wrong with `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9/]+" title="Numbers and slashes only" />`?

Comment: so your saying my code should work for the numeric key pad?

Comment: @DomAdams No your code will not work as long as you use `keydown`. The numeric keypad is a different set of keycodes. They are equal with the `keypress` event. Try my answer.

Comment: @DomAdams, how about validating on blur event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my answer.. there are charCode for the numpads didnt see it

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Woop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```js
function handleInputKey(e)
{
    if (!e)
    {
        var e = window.event;
    }

    //allow only numeric input
    //48-57 and 96-105 (keyboard left and numpad)
    if ( ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 || e.keyCode == 47) && (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey) ))
    {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;

    }


}

 document.getElementById('txtbox').addEventListener("keypress", handleInputKey, false);
```

```html
Please input date in DD/MM/YYYY format.<br />
<input id="txtbox" maxlength="10" placeholder="example: 01/01/1970">
```

Comment: How would I know, that wasn't part of your question. It's plain JavaScript as is your solution, so I guess so.

Comment: this will not work for my knockout as everything gets rendered after the DOM

Comment: How is your function working then? Because when properly initialized on your page this code should work just perfect.

Comment: im calling a data-bind="value: Birthdate, valueUpdate: 'keyup', event: { keyup: CheckDate}"

Comment: `data-bind="value: Birthdate, valueUpdate: 'keyup', event: { keypress: handleInputKey}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to input a date, use:

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Supporting browsers will provide a calendar for the user to select from in all convenience.

On the server-side, you will receive a date in the standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: Yes and 10% of the users with IE won't

Comment: is that compatible for IE?

Comment: @Mouser That's what polyfills were invented for. They provide user-friendly features. Blocking certain characters without providing feedback is not the way to go.

Comment: Yes but using a native element that isn't fully supported isn't a great answer. My code works on all browsers and a simple message like the label above my input and a sample placeholder should tell the user enough. The OP couldn't however get it to work with Knockout. That's a shame.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example as a work around using `blur` event and `RegExp`:

```js
var txtbox = document.getElementById('txtbox');

var mask = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

txtbox.value = mask;

txtbox.onfocus = function(e) {
  if (mask === txtbox.value) { //put mask when no value is entered
    txtbox.value = '';
  }
};

var ptrn = /([0-3][0-9]\/)([0|1][1-9]\/)\d{4}/;//RegExp date pattern dd/mm/yyyy

txtbox.onblur = function(e) {
  var val = txtbox.value;
  var valid = true;
  if (val && !ptrn.test(val)) {//no value or does not matches pattern
    valid = false;
  }
  if(valid) {//date was entered in required pattern
    val = val.replace(ptrn, '$2$1$3');//making string in mm/dd/yyyy as required by date constructor
    if(!new Date(val)) {//not a valid date object
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  if(!valid) {
    alert('Invalid date !');
    val = '';
  }
  if ('' === val) { //put mask when no value
    txtbox.value = mask;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txtbox' maxlength='10' />
```